# How does std::vec::shrink_to_fit work in Rust?

Tags: rust, vector, heap-memory, allocator

Does `std::vec::shrink_to_fit` allocate a new, smaller `vec.len()` buffer of data, copy to it, and destruct the old buffer, or does it somehow indicate to the memory allocator that the uninitialised part of the buffer can be de-allocated, and simply release that part of the memory? Is that even possible? Does that depend on the memory allocator?

And a tangential question which I apologise to ask here, but if that's possible, why don't we, for example, implement popping from the front of a vector as a simple "release `std::mem::size_of<T>()` amount of memory from the start of the buffer, and increment our pointer by one", rather than shifting all our elements by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Vec::shrink_to_fit()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) uses the [Allocator::shrink()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html#method.shrink) method to shrink the allocation (via the internal [RawVec::shrink_to_fit()](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/03761a50a3b26daded09e6da79252692c9bbad5f/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs#L356), method which may simply resize the existing allocation in-place without moving the data, or it might return a different memory block.

You can't pop from the front of a vector by re-sizing it, because memory allocations can't have their start address changed, only their length.

Answer (score 5):

The beautiful thing about rust's documentation is that you can see for yourself! Rust's documentation includes the source code of **whole crate** and standard library is written very well and you can read it's source code and understand it (and learn **a lot** from it) even if you are not rust guru.

So let's see what is the answer to your question.

- To the right of method [Vec::shrink_to_fit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) you have a link to source code
- It directs us to this method [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#1041)
- there we are calling `shrink_to_fit(self.len)` on `self.buf` which is of type `RawVec`
- In the file tree on the left we can go to [raw_vec.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html)
- On line [#357](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#357) we have implementation of `shrink_to_fit` for `RawVec`. It in turn calls `RawVec::shrink` which is implemented below on line [#430](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#430)
- There we can finally see that on line [#442](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#442) this function calls `self.alloc.shrink`. It is a method on unstable [Allocator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html#method.shrink) trait

Now this function can be implemented in different ways by different allocators. Some might do a realloc, and some might perform actual shrinking of the memory and **do not** `memmove` anything. To see what your program uses you must learn more about your allocator.

If you look at [Allocator's](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html) methods you will see that there is no method `shrink_from_start`. This is because that operation isn't a common one and would be much harder to implement in an allocator. That's why using it to implement `Vec::remove(0)` wouldn't have much sense.

Comment: I actually tried to, but I gave up right after RawVec::shrink since it got a bit too nested for me and didn't look for what alloc.shrink is

Comment: Great detailed answer, this is what I did in order to try and answer the question. :) There's no other language/platform with such easy and rich docs and source access like this. Really awesome.